# Copy firefox/thunderbird config directories from Ubuntu 12.04 to Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, configuration, thunderbird, home-directory

I have an old horse (P4 3.2 - 2gb - 128mb 9250Ati) running Ubuntu 12.04.

Since 12.04 support ended recently i tried to update to 14.04 but the result was disappointing.

I'm going to Xubuntu 16.04 and I want to know if I can copy-paste the Firefox and Thunderbird hidden folders from my current Ubuntu home directory to my new Xubuntu installation.

Is it possible, or will I have compatibility problems?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You should be able to copy files/folders from your Home folder from Ubuntu to Xubuntu without any issues. Firefox and Thunderbird profiles should work fine since both Ubuntu and Xubuntu use the same version (or at least very close to the same version).

For other folders, especially the hidden ones, it should be fine to copy them over as well. You might want to be careful about overwriting existing files/folders since Xubuntu may have some differences in configuration.

As always, it is recommended to back up your home folder before install/reinstalling OSes.